# Javascript .match() method output

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having an issue with the .match() method in Javascript.

For example, I am running:

```
"EY1 F AO1 R T UW1 W AH1 N T UW1 EY1 T".match(/\d/);
```

and logging the result, and the output I am getting is:

```
[ '1', index: 2, input: 'EY1 F AO1 R T UW1 W AH1 N T UW1 EY1 T' ]
```

My understanding is that I am supposed to get an array of all of the matches in a selection, rather than this output, so I should get something like [1,1,1,1,1,1].  Has anybody encountered this problem before or have any idea how to get the correct output?

Thanks.

Comment: Use global regex `/\d/g`

Comment: @elclanrs, you should submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp isn't set to do a `global` match.

Change your code to `"EY1 F AO1 R T UW1 W AH1 N T UW1 EY1 T".match(/\d/g);` and I think you will get what you are looking for.